# Azure ML pipeline runs slowly due to AppInsights

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-machine-learning-service

I have set up an Azure ML pipeline with a single Python script step. Provided that the compute has already been spun up, initially the pipeline took around 2 minutes with an `executionlogs.txt` like so:

```
[2020-09-23 22:36:14Z] Experiment: <EXPERIMENT>
[2020-09-23 22:36:14Z] Run Id:     <RUN_ID>
[2020-09-23 22:36:14Z] Run target: <RUN_TARGET>
[2020-09-23 22:36:14Z] Starting run in Execution Service
[2020-09-23 22:36:17Z] RunId:[<RUN_ID>] ParentRunId:[<PARENT_RUN_ID>] ComputeTarget:[AmlCompute]
[2020-09-23 22:36:19Z] Job is running, job runstatus is Queued
[2020-09-23 22:36:30Z] Job is running, job runstatus is Running
[2020-09-23 22:38:19Z] Job is running, job runstatus is Running
[2020-09-23 22:38:31Z] Job is running, job runstatus is Finalizing
[2020-09-23 22:38:40Z] Job finished, job RunId is <RUN_ID>
```

Now, with the same spun-up compute and code, I'm finding a run time that is 3 times larger:

```
[2020-10-14 17:14:23Z] Experiment: <EXPERIMENT>
[2020-10-14 17:14:23Z] Run Id:     <RUN_ID>
[2020-10-14 17:14:23Z] Run target: <RUN_TARGET>
[2020-10-14 17:14:23Z] Starting run in Execution Service
[2020-10-14 17:14:26Z] RunId:[<RUN_ID>] ParentRunId:[<PARENT_RUN_ID>] ComputeTarget:[AmlCompute]
[2020-10-14 17:14:31Z] Job is running, job runstatus is Queued
[2020-10-14 17:14:40Z] Job is running, job runstatus is Running
[2020-10-14 17:16:26Z] Job is running, job runstatus is Running
[2020-10-14 17:18:27Z] Job is running, job runstatus is Running
[2020-10-14 17:19:08Z] Job is running, job runstatus is Finalizing
[2020-10-14 17:20:28Z] Job is running, job runstatus is Finalizing
[2020-10-14 17:21:10Z] Job finished, job RunId is <RUN_ID>
```

Even 'Finalize' to 'Finish' takes over 2 minutes now! The run times for `70_driver_log.txt` are similar for both runs.

I identified a difference in the `55_azureml-execution-tvmps_....txt` log. My slow runs contain the following line related to application insights:

```
appinsightlogger.go:42: Time Out after 20 second retries for flushing the logs, doing another retry before exiting
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you use some SDK? Or do you submit to REST endpoint directly? Are you blocking your script while submit data to Application Insights?

Comment: This happens both when the pipeline is called using the Python SDK and when it is called from an ADF pipeline. My code does not contain custom logging--could there still be blocking from any default logging?

Comment: Can you please point to Python SDK you use?